# Shortcut key for select @name

Tags: discussion, chat, user-interface

Is there a keyboard shortcut available to select @name from options?

A shortcut will really be very helpful in a long conversation.

[image]

Comment: If you press tab, it will select the first item. Continue pressing tab to iterate the options

Comment: oh thanks @Rob . I just used it :)

Comment: Why are the gravatars missing in your screenshot?

Comment: @rene If I am right stackoverflow using imgur and imgur is block from my side. not only imgur but all file storage and sharing site is block that is why.

Comment: @KDeogharkar ah, that explains it. It was the first thing that I noticed. :D

Comment: yes even I can't see screenshot. your question confirmed that my image is there in question :) @rene

Comment: Glad I'm not the only here with a company proxy blocking imgur... Meta is not fun with images blocked :(.

Comment: yes you are right @Tunaki

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I would strongly recommend [this user-script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments). With it, you even don't need to type `@` yourself.

Comment: This is nice for all those people with wéî®∂ çhå®åç†é®ß in their name.